# Why variable button is assigned window object and how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to assign `const button= e.currentTarget;` with button element when clicked, but it is assigned with window object and due to this the `const container= button.parentNode;` is also not working. Can you solve this error.
I am only mentioning the section element in which button and container is present.

```js
     window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
       const orderButtons = document.querySelectorAll("button[data-order]");
       orderButtons.forEach(function(button){

        window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

            //button is assigned with window object, should be assigned clicked button
 
            const button= e.currentTarget; 
            const container= button.parentNode;

            const order={
                id: button.getAttribute("data-order"),
                title: container.querySelector(".title").innerText,
                price: container.querySelector(".price").innerText,
                desc: container.querySelector(".desc").innerText
            };
           
            localStorage.setItem("order", JSON.stringify(order));

            const url= window.location.href.replace("pies.html","order.html");
            window.location.href=url;
        });
       });
   });
```

```html
    <section class="desktop-column">
             <div class="pie">
                 <img src="images/apple-pie.png" alt="Apple Pie">
                 <div class="columns">
                    <div class="title">Apple Pie</div>
                    <div class="price">300 ₹</div>
                 </div>
                 <p class="desc">Our famous pie.</p>
                 <button data-order="apple-pie">Order</button>
                </div>

                <div class="pie">
                    <img src="images/cherry-pie.png" alt="Cherry Pie">
                    <div class="columns">
                       <div class="title">Cherry Pie</div>
                       <div class="price">340 ₹</div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="desc">Our summer classic!.</p>
                    <button data-order="cherry-pie">Order</button>
                   </div>
         </section>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the code above the error is event listener is called at `window` object

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
const button= e.currentTarget; 
const container= button.parentNode;
```

that's why when `button` is assigned `currentTarget` window object is assigned, and there is no `parentNode` for window object that's why `container` is `undefined`.

```
           `const order={
            id: button.getAttribute("data-order"),
            title: container.querySelector(".title").innerText,
            price: container.querySelector(".price").innerText,
            desc: container.querySelector(".desc").innerText
        };`
```

Due to `container` and `button`'s wrong value `getAttribute querySelector` are unable to select DOM elements which leads to `Uncaught TypeError`

Correct Code snippet-

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        const button= e.currentTarget;
        const container= button.parentNode;
        const order={
            id: button.getAttribute("data-order"),
            title: container.querySelector(".title").innerText,
            price: container.querySelector(".price").innerText,
            desc: container.querySelector(".desc").innerText
        };
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

`currentTarget` is the element to which the event handler is bound.

You want plain `target` for the element on which the event was initially triggered.

Comment: Thank you Quentin it is working now, but can you explain why currentTarget is not and target is working and how to make it work?

Comment: The problem with your solution is that it is executing even when I click anywhere on container, how to make it button specific only?

Comment: @SohamMalviya see my answer

Comment: @SimoneRossaini — `currentTarget` doesn't work and `target` does because they are different things, I explained the difference in the answer. If you want to only handle a click when a button is clicked test the `tagName` of the `target` to see if it the right kind of element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want take `data-order` of button you press like:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
       const orderButtons = document.querySelectorAll("button[data-order]");
       orderButtons.forEach(function(button){

        button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

            //button is assigned with window object, should be assigned clicked button
            
            const container= this.parentNode;

            const order={
                id: this.getAttribute("data-order"),
                title: container.querySelector(".title").innerText,
                price: container.querySelector(".price").innerText,
                desc: container.querySelector(".desc").innerText
            };
           
            console.log(order);
        });
       });
   });
```

```html
<section class="desktop-column">
             <div class="pie">
                 <img src="images/apple-pie.png" alt="Apple Pie">
                 <div class="columns">
                    <div class="title">Apple Pie</div>
                    <div class="price">300 ₹</div>
                 </div>
                 <p class="desc">Our famous pie.</p>
                 <button data-order="apple-pie">Order</button>
                </div>

                <div class="pie">
                    <img src="images/cherry-pie.png" alt="Cherry Pie">
                    <div class="columns">
                       <div class="title">Cherry Pie</div>
                       <div class="price">340 ₹</div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="desc">Our summer classic!.</p>
                    <button data-order="cherry-pie">Order</button>
                   </div>
         </section>
```

Note: i change `localStorage()` to `console.log()` for snippet